# Как называется эта застежка?

Tags: названия

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как называются эти крепящиеся приспособления на куртке, эта разновидность застежки? Петля, кнопка? Затычка и втулка имеют различные названия?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не о русском языке.

Comment: Протестую. Вопрос нужно оставить. Сам много раз получал ответы на похожие вопросы именно здесь. Это вопрос именно о русском языке: термины, значения слов и  в том же духе.

Comment: Действительно, а о чем данный вопрос, как не о русском?

Answer (score 3):

Кнопка. Но не простая, а

[«ДЖЕРСИ»](https://burdastyle.ru/master-klassy/tkani/knopki-i-kryuchki-dlya-odezhdy-vidy-otlichiya-primenenie_13166/)

> Это пробивающиеся кнопки. Они имеют 5 металлических зубчиков, которые
>   вдавливаются в ткань, при этом, не повреждая её. Подходят для
>   застежек, рассчитанных на легкую и среднюю нагрузку.

А возможно, и **усиковая**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вариант, **пробивающиеся кнопки**:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Подходят для анораков, спортивной одежды, изделий из джинсовой ткани.
>   Чтобы закрепить такую кнопку, на ткани пробивают маленькие дырочки и
>   устанавливают металлические части кнопки с помощью специальных
>   инструментов, которые продаются обычно в наборе вместе с кнопками и
>   люверсами разных размеров.

Answer (score 1):

Всегда слышал, что эти штуки называли "кнопки". Думаю, также применимо "заклёпки". Чтобы совсем наверняка "кнопка-заклёпка". Но, конечно, точный ответ проще найти в каталоге подобной продукции.